# Enable/Disable keyboard AccessoryBar ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

How to hide or show keyboard accessory bar in Ionic 2 ? 
When I was using Ionic 1.3 this can be done through the app.js file at module run on platform ready event. by modifying below a line.

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
```

to

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

In Ionic 2 beta11,I used http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/keyboard/
Native Keyboard plugin and imported in app.ts
and then inside constructor at platform ready, I used hideKeyboardAccessoryBar method of Keyboard to set the property to false. but it did not work.
the accessory bar is not appearing with the keyboard.

```
// Call any initial plugins when ready
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
```

Comment: When i open the application, there is no accessoryBar shown, but when i click on some input field and then close the keyboard, the accessoryBar still stay vissible and i want to hide it...
I've tried using Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); in  Keyboard.onKeyboardHide() event but without success...